# How to transform an image to another coordinates?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, emgucv, image-scaling

I am trying to find duplicate videos in my database, and in order to do so I grab two frames from a videos pair, resize them to the same width and height and then compare both images pixel by pixel.

I have a case where images from the a videos pair are like below:

[image]   -----    [image]

These are actually the same videos (images), but because of the aspect ratio of the videos (16:9, 4:3 .. etc) the result is negative when comparing pixel by pixel (no match).

If my standard is 50x50, how can I transform ***any*** Region Of Interest to 50x50?

For the above example:

> Pixel [5,0] shall be [0,0]
>
> Pixel [45,0] shall be [50,0]
>
> Pixel [5,50] shall be [0,50]
>
> Pixel [45,50] shall be [50,50]
>
> and all other pixels are **transformed**

Comment: Do you ask for name of specific functions of a certain library, or image-processing algorithm (pseudo-code can do)?

Comment: @javaLover just anything..  I am asking for a solution and I am using EmguCV with C#. I habe the contour and I want to transgkrm it. Do you know a specific function or an algorithm? Pseudo is fine

Comment: Is input (`any Region Of Interest`) always a rectangle that perfectly align to axis X and Y (strict ROI meaning in opencv)?  Is the transform just scale & move only?  Rotate? Can input skew?   or input can be [**any** quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral) including Concave Quadrilaterals?  Or the ROI could be even a polygon or a circle?

Comment: It is always a rectangle, since I [4. Contour Approximation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) my contour with 10%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encouraged by OP that pseudo-code can be helpful ....
I have no knowledge about "emgucv", so I will answer in pseudo-code.

### **Definition**

Let `SRC` be a source image - to be read.
Let `DST` be a destination image - to be written.

Both `SRC` and `DST` are 2D-array, can be accessed as `ARRAY[int pixelX,int pixelY]`.

**Here is the pseudo-code :-**

```
input : int srcMinX,srcMinY,srcMaxX,srcMaxY;
float linearGra(float dst1,float dst2,float src1,float src2,float dst3){
    return ( (dst3-dst1)*src2+  (dst2-dst3)*src1) / (dst2-dst1);
};
for(int y=0;y<50;y++){     //y of DST
    for(int x=0;x<50;x++){ //x of DST
        float xSRC=linearGra(0,50,srcMinX,srcMaxX,x);
        float ySRC=linearGra(0,50,srcMinY,srcMaxY,y);
        DST[x,y]=SRC[round(xSRC),round(ySRC)];  //find nearest pixel
    }
}
```

### Description

The main idea is to use [linear-interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

The function `linearGra` takes two points in a 2D graph `(dst1,src1)` and `(dst2,src2)` .

Assuming that it is a linear function (it is true because `scaling+moving` is linear function between `SRC` and `DST` coordinate), it will find the point `(dst3,?)` that lying in the graph.

I used this function to calculate pixel coordinate in `SRC` that match a certain pixel in `DST`.

### Further work

If you are a perfectionist, you may want to :-

- bounded the index `(xSRC,ySRC)` - so it will not index-out-of-bound
- improve the accurary :-
  I currently ignore some pixels (I use Nearest-neighbor w/o interpolation).
  The better approach is to [integrate all involved `SRC`'s pixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering), but you will get a-bit-blurry image in some cases.

You may also be interested in [this opencv link (not emgucv)](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html).

Comment: Beautiful. I will go ahead and try that. And by the way, EmguCV is just an OpenCV wrapper for C#; so everything in OpenCV is in EmguCV as well. FYI thing and thanks again :)